# Python - multi-line array

Tags: python, arrays

in c++ I can wrote:

```
int someArray[8][8];
for (int i=0; i < 7; i++)
   for (int j=0; j < 7; j++)
      someArray[i][j] = 0;
```

And how can I initialize multi-line arrays in python?
I tried:

```
array = [[],[]]
for i in xrange(8):
   for j in xrange(8):
        array[i][j] = 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> [[0]*8 for x in xrange(8)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

You asked about initializing a list of lists. Its a very useful data structure, but it has an important difference from the 2D array in C++: There are no guarantees that all lines have the same length (i.e, that `len(a[0])==len(a[1])` (while in C++ you do have that guarantee).

So another solution that might be handy, is using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/)'s [array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array) datatype, like this:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros((8,8))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter way:

```
array = []
for i in xrange(8):
    array.append( [0] * 8 )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array = [[0]*8 for i in xrange(8)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[0]*8 for x in range(8)]
```